# Is capturing known keyboard shortcuts such as F5 a bad UX?

Tags: user-expectation, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a website that has an editable table with data in it.

Is capturing <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh data (with clear notification that the data was refreshed) instead of refreshing the entire page bad user experience?

Can we assume that users who know about <kbd>F5</kbd> also know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>? Should i come up with another keyboard shortcut such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> instead?

Comment: I would argue that this question is equivalent to "Is breaking expected behavior bad UX?" to which the obvious answer is "yes".

Comment: If you are thinking that multiple people may be working on the form at a single time you will have to take into consider race conditions and then have some mechanism to inform users of this. I'd also put in something to automatically refresh only the data without reloading the page with a brief message that appears notifying the user of such. As many have said changing expected behavior isn't a good idea. Look for other approaches to refresh.

Comment: On Mac F5 does not have that meaning.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't mind using F5 to refresh the data in the context of the app, assuming it makes sense. If it's not too much hassle, default it to a non-conflicting key, and allow the user to remap to F5 if they want to. After all, just because F5 can't refresh the entire app doesn't mean I still can't use Ctrl+R (which I'd more likely to do an actual refresh), or use the Refresh button on the browser.

Comment: Why would you assume that any of these are not unique to a particular browser, if not actually configurable by the user?

Comment: Just allow them to disable your F5 capture and you’ll be fine

Comment: Merely an anecdote: I was working with Lotus 1-2-3 some years ago, and it had existed since the age of the dinosaurs. I was already used to pressing F5 for refresh, but with Lotus, F5 was (and always had been) used for Logout. So every time I went to refresh my emails... logged out. Hugely frustrating. F9 was refresh for Lotus. It worked in isolation, but as soon as you start fighting against whatever has become user expectation, you start frustrating your users.

Comment: Some websites are replacing default browser search functionality with their own by overriding CTRL+F. This can be unexpected and annoying, although opinions on this topic are mixed, examples I found on SE sites: [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/keyboard-shortcuts-overriding-default-browser-action), [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997901/override-browsers-search-feature-ctrlf-but-reuse-its-native-search-field), [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22033/ctrl-f-not-working-for-browser-page-search-when-using-google-docs)

Comment: @flith http://hallofshame.gp.co.at/index.php?file=lotus.htm&mode=original ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't say that just because someone knows F5 that they will know CTRL R. There's nothing wrong though with a subtle yet noticeable popup that fades away that shows you can refresh with CTRL R. Maybe a suggestion that pops up if they manually click refresh too many times. And once CTRL R is used a few times that popup shouldn't appear anymore. I'm not a UX designer. I'm just giving the opinion of someone who likes to use computers.

Comment: I once used a website which had done exactly that... my F5 was captured and the website showed me that it was fetching it's (maybe updated) content via ajax. My reaction was hitting CTRL+F5 instantly. If i wanna **reload** the site, you better let me **reload** the page or i will be mad at you. (Side note: I never knew that CTRL+R also refreshes the page :D)

Comment: "to refresh data" - `F9` is the "standard" shortcut to refresh/recalc spreadsheets (MS Excel, OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc, ...), so maybe that would be more appropriate? `F9` is not assigned to anything else in the browser that I'm aware?

Comment: It's a browser UX bug (and in related situations, probably even a browser security bug) if the browser even lets you do this.

Comment: As was pointed out earlier F5 does not mean anything for macs but in addition to that Ctrl-R also means nothing on a mac as the refresh keystroke is Cmd-R so if you are depending on something with F5 or Ctrl-R it will not work on a mac.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen so you're saying that Macs are bad UX?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No.  Doing the proper research on making web applications accessible to handicapped users, would be proper UX.

Comment: one notable example is gerrit, which captures all common shortcut keys like Ctrl+T, Ctrl+S, Ctrl+R... There are a lot of complaints about that and I've read questions about how to disable it but none of them is usable

Comment: It is generally not advisable to assume anything about your users (when you don't know much about them) :p

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Repurposing familiar controls to do other things is generally a bad idea as it simply means that they don't behave as the user expects them to.

If you are augmenting a control set then it's best to avoid existing controls and add new ones. That way, the controls that users are familiar with will behave as expected.

Comment: Does this apply to redefining e.g. the right click as many web applications do?

Comment: @PierreArlaud What do you mean by "redefine"? How is that different from "repurpose"?

Comment: @PierreArlaud I imagine the overriding default behavior is done based on an average user.  For example, F1 is generally to open help.  I could see web applications overriding it so you get help related to the page you are on rather than for the browser.

Comment: But there you have the problem. People may interact with your site and be annoyed by the site taking over keys. They press F1 to look up in the browser help if they can disable this (Firefox will introduce such a function soon) and then your site intercepts even this key. Never change something users are used to. Even overriding right click menus is bad UX, despite many sites doing so. And do you remember ``onrightclick=alert("don't steal my source code!")``?

Comment: @PierreArlaud The right click is always contextual - it's purpose is to give you a menu that is relevant for where the click happened. This is a pattern that users are familiar with - they a familiar with the fact that the right click menu will change relative to the click action. Therefore the pattern does not change.

Comment: @AndrewMartin It's still an astonishment. Why am I getting a flash player contextual menu when I was trying to download the background image? Besides, my question was pretty rhethorical, although I do agree it's really annoying that for instance the web client for outlook redefines Ctrl-R as a "reply" command.

Comment: @PierreArlaud Ctrl-R is the 'reply' command for Outlook - that's why they've chosen to claim that particular combination - so that the user has commands that they are familiar with in the context of Outlook. The contextual menu under right click is only surprising in the case of Flash because many users do not understand what Flash is and why it should have an unusual contextual menu - this is simply a reason not to use Flash.

Comment: @PierreArlaud In my opinion, the problem is more complex than that. This is a problem of websites becoming applications, and browser - a framework for them. How would you design Google Docs app without a custom context menu?

Comment: @AndrewMartin I don't think the problem is limited to Flash at all. If I right click on something, I expect to have some specific options - e.g. copy image, copy image location, open in new tab, so on and so forth - of which I'll want to do one. If you repurpose the right click menu to do other things, even if it's still contextually relevant to what I clicked on, then you've broken my expectations and denied me from doing an action that I wanted, which is horrible UX. This goes for Flash or non-Flash content.

Comment: @cubuspl42 and AndrewMartin: That's pretty much the point I was trying to make, it might make sense for web apps to redefine shortcuts, or maybe it just doesn't. This is why just answering "it's generally a bad idea" is not a satisfying answer to me, I think we need actual studies and results to see how users feel about web apps playing with their usual keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: This is the last response I'm going to make here: I used the word 'generally' because, although it's most often a bad idea, sometimes it actually works (see the Outlook reference above). I also used the concept of familiarity as the main factor for deciding what will and won't work for users. You won't find generalised studies because you can't test this as a general rule but what you will find is studies about breaking expectations and I invite you to find them and post the links here.

Comment: @cubuspl42 The context menu case could be solved fairly easily by the browser not allowing the application to replace the menu but rather allowing it to extend the context menu. If a clear distinction between menu items from the page and from the browser is needed one could be made a submenu of the other.

Comment: @kasperd There's the [`<menu>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu) which allows that (except for the "clear distinction" part). It's supported by Firefox, Edge and Opera. Sadly [it was removed from Chrome/Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87553&desc=2).

Comment: I fail to see how hijacking F5 to refresh data is any different than hijacking the back button by [modifying history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries), and the latter is rather commonly supported in webapps.

Comment: _Even overriding right click menus is bad UX, despite many sites doing so._ My personal user experience is just the opposite. I love it when a web application provides a useful right click menu, just like a desktop application. The browser's native right click menu is nearly useless in a web application.

Answer (score 57):

Taking over existing keyboard shortcuts (in the scope of the application the user is working in) is a horrible idea.

You don't explicitly state it, but I think your application is browser based. Since, in the context of the browser, <kbd>F5</kbd> is an existing keyboard shortcut (a common one, at that), it is a bad idea.

From personal experience - I had Norton AV installed and my subscription had expired. I didn't want to renew immediately. After it expired, the app took over the <kbd>F5</kbd> shortcut as such that when I pressed it, it loaded an "always on top" modal with the Norton renewal advertisements. It did this *regardless of what app I was using at the time*. This was so intrusive to the standard behavior *i was expecting*, I ended up uninstalling and stopped all of my business with the company.

This inconsistency between the behavior I *expected* and what actually happened creates a feeling of friction against the task I am trying to accomplish. I am one of those people who *can physically feel the energy drain from my body* when this type of friction occurs, which in turn, can cause your users to leave.

It would almost be like adding a new car stereo to your car that took over the gas-pedal as a way to increase or lower the volume. It's an extreme example, I know, but that's how these things feel to me.

For another example... in Chrome, in the past, the backspace button could be used to take the user back to the last page they were on (equivalent to hitting the back button on the browser). They disabled that, in favor of the proper <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>back arrow</kbd>. Thousands of Chrome users [took to the support forums to protest](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/D4VMOXTxPwg).

Instead, perhaps have a refresh icon or button next to (or above/below) the table which a user can focus to with a single <kbd>TAB</kbd> key press when currently focused on/working on the grid. Once it is focused, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or a click with the mouse) should trigger it. If you must, you can create a new keyboard shortcut to activate it as well, ensuring that it isn't one that is already assigned to a behavior already by the browser.

Comment: Off-topic comment, but just goes to show that the antivirus can easily be as bad as some of the malware it's supposed to keep out...

Comment: @RomanSt Norton antivirus has famously detected *itself* as a virus in the past. :)

Comment: Part of the problem with the Chrome change is that the new shortcut is Alt + Left Arrow, not Alt + Backspace, despite the hint shown suggesting the latter. That, and Backspace being the keyboard shortcut for going back a page for decades, in lots of software.

Comment: Backspace key was a bad example; that was just a bug from the beginning. A key which does something dangerously different depending on whether focus is on in a text input box or something else is atrociously bad UX.

Comment: Chrome is a well established software from Google. Surely they have thought carefully about this, right? Did they explain it, and why didn't people agree with it? And in general, is there a way to transfer a bad habit to a good one smoothly?

Comment: Related xkcd: [Borrow Your Laptop](https://xkcd.com/1806/)

Comment: Oh man! It's the same with the awful web app "Confluence". It breaks things like opening a new window to view another web site. If I wasn't required to use it for work, I would never use any of their products again.

Comment: Just my two-cents in regards to Chrome's decision to use Alt + back arrow exclusively. There have been plenty of times in which I am working on a form, tabbing/shift+tabbing from one field to another, and at some point I wish to simply delete the contents of a field. Normally this works but sometimes I end up on some sort of click-able text, icon, question mark, etc and bamm-o! by the time I look up from the keyboard I have magically ended up on some web page from hours ago and all of my form data is lost even though I press forward until I return to my form. I support Google's decision.

Comment: ...The real, "What the heck?" here is that you were using Norton in the first place.

Answer (score 22):

Always follow the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). The use of <kbd>F5</kbd> in this situation would be considered astonishing.

There are cases when keys should be overridden in order to provide the least surprising behaviour. A common case is applications that are traditionally desktop based but are now running in a browser window that acts as a thin shell. In this case it would be logical  to override (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>super</kbd>)<kbd>O</kbd> to open a document as part of your application rather than within the browser.

---

In your particular case, I wonder if it's necessary for the user to manually refresh the table. It may be better for the data to automagically update so that it's always current. If a user's changes need to be explicitly committed then an override of (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>super</kbd>)<kbd>S</kbd> to perform this action would make sense.

Answer (score 12):

The only time I have ever done this, was with an internal systems diagnostic web page that allowed admin users to enter raw a raw SQL query to run against a database.

The users were accustomed to using SQL Server Management Studio, which executed the query using the `F5` shortcut.  Users complained that pressing `F5` would refresh the page, making them lose their query.  Pressing `F5` was so ingrained in muscle memory for them that, even though they knew it would refresh the page, they hit that key automatically to run the query.

After updating the page to capture `F5` and cause it to run the query instead, the users were *much* happier.

Comment: alternative solutions would be to a) ask the user if he wants to leave the page when a query is in the page (`onbeforeunload`) or b) to save the query in `localStorage` and restore it after reloading the page

Answer (score 4):

There are times when it is acceptable to "capture" controls to do common things the browser didn't intend to do. But they are very limited. They should not be a rule of thumb but an exception.

For example if you press F5 while adding an answer you get a dialog asking "Are you sure" (essentially). While "capturing" the navigate away from page (the refresh) is generally bad, in this case it's a good thing.

Other really good examples are right click context menus in complicated web applications. For example Reports that intercept right click to "download as PDF" or "download as Excel". May WYSIWYG text editors capture and replace the right click.

If used very carefully, it can be a great tool. If abused it can make you UX worse then a puppy-murdering cannibal. The trick is to only do it when nothing else makes sense. When there is no other way, and when your 100% certain that the original action is not the action the user would actually want.

P.S. For this answer I'm not counting the fact that the the dialog happens on navigation and not on key press, just that it pops if you smash F5.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers make it clear that breaking expected behaviour is bad UX. I would like to make the additional point that you do not know what the user's keyboard looks like, and what their existing keyboard shortcuts are: **defining keyboard shortcuts with no way to change them is also bad UX.**

It is therefore good practice to implement keyboard shortcuts as follows:

1. Your web application defines several actions, such as "Refresh table" or "Move to next table"
2. Your web application binds these actions to sensible default keys, such as <kbd>r</kbd> for "Refresh table" and <kbd>n</kbd> for "Move to next table".
3. The user can adjust the keybindings in the web application's settings.

Two examples:

- An Ukrainian user might want to bind "Move next table" to the <kbd>д</kbd> key, for дальший.
- A user of the Vivaldi browser might have <kbd>r</kbd> (for 'rectangle') already bound to "Capture Area to File"; now they can't refresh a table without entering screenshot mode. They enter your settings, and bind "Refresh table" to <kbd>u</kbd> (for 'update), instead.

Answer (score 3):

Having established that changing the action of well-established keyboard shortcuts is bad UX, here is a suggestion for better UX:

Detect when the user has pressed **F5** or **Cmd-R** to reload the page, and show them a "did you know?" popup to advertise your custom keyboard shortcut:

> You can press **Ctrl Alt R** at any time to quickly refresh the table data

#discoverability

You might also want to reduce the annoyance of this popup by: only showing it once per day, or only on pages with a table, or only until the user has used the shortcut a few times.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually executed poorly and/or in an attempt to enforce some kind of DRM/"stealing" protection. When I do intercept the default controls in the browser, it's only to fix glitches that sometimes appear with a complicated AJAX-driven layout changing what the user sees. For example when the mouse wheel or the arrows scroll the wrong part of the page instead of what has been overlaid by the script. Then I also hooked the ESC key that normally aborts the loading of the page and stops GIF animations to only abort and close the thing loading in an overlay. I also changed the drag behavior from its default drag-and-drop to something like what you see on Maps sites. It will control the scrolling.
But I still offer the user the option to select between viewing modes and these wild features are disabled by default.

Comment: Pages that hook ESC annoy me.

Comment: If they are ad popups, yes. My implementation is useful though and I wager you would use it naturally as I intended it and you wouldn't even realize your hate could be triggered. Plus only the first press is hooked to close the overlay; the next one is already handled by the browser normally.

Comment: Yes, it's generally pages that use JS for obnoxious reasons, for instance initially displaying the content and then deciding they don't like the fact I use an adblocker so will yank the content and replace it with a whinge.   If the original use of JS isn't obnoxious, then I probably don't want to kill it off.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case of F5/reload, I would instead recommend implementing a [service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) for your site, which would handle local caching of all your page's assets.

This way, the page won't be refreshed (from the server) unless you specify it, whereas the data will always be updated.

For the user, the effect is exactly the one you want - only the data is refreshed. But the expected functionality remains in place, as it should from a UX POV.

Comment: The problem with this is that if I as a user press F5 and I don't see the data change because it's cached locally, I will feel like the page is broken. Even if I only loaded the page 5 seconds ago and the data is autorenewed every 15 seconds, I still want to see the data refresh, especially if it's time-based data. Like, if your page shows something's progression or someone's location, if I refresh the page, i want up to date information. I don't want to see the situation from 60 seconds ago, especially if I loaded the page 10 seconds ago. Apple Find my Friends does that and it pisses me off.